# Failing to rename a column involved in partition in MySQL

Tags: mysql, partitioning, typeorm, alter-table

I have created a table with the following query.
CREATE table IF NOT EXISTS `result`(id varchar(255) not null, product varchar(255), prodcount int, searched_at datetime default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, primary key (id, product, searched_at)) partition by hash(yearweek(searched_at))

Now I need to change the column name of searched_at to created_at. While using AlterTable command, I am getting the following error:
"Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'searched_at' in 'partition function'"
It seems that there is already a bug raised in MySQL: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=85413
Does this issue have any workarounds?

Comment: drop partitioning, rename, add partitioing

Answer (score -1):

Well, you probably have to start with `ALTER TABLE table DROP PARTITIONING`.

However, I would recommend stopping there, except for fixing the indexes. 
 `PARITITION BY HASH()` probably has *no* viable use case.

It sounds like you may be searching on a date range?  If so, `BY HASH` will touch all the partitions because, for all it knows, the data is wrapped every year.

Pleas provide the important queries; I will help you redo the indexes.